# 307 redirect with Authorization header

Tags: go, redirect

In looking at the [Go docs](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=708:1583) for http it looks like the `Authorization` header is removed when a response is a `307`.  Obviously it makes sense for almost every case but is there a way not to remove the `Authorization` header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your `http.Client` to add the header again after it has been removed using [`CheckRedirect`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect):

```
CheckRedirect func(req *Request, via []*Request) error
```

Since `req` is the upcoming request, it can be modified before it is sent. After making the changes, return `nil` to indicate that the request should still be sent.

Since this is a change to the http client instead of the request, you should check that this redirect is only used for the one URL where you need it (in case you use that client to do other requests).

You client definition could look like this:

```
http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        // you can check old responses for a status code
        if len(via) != 0 && via[0].Response.StatusCode == http.StatusTemporaryRedirect {
            req.Header.Add("Authorization", "some-value")
        }
        return nil
    },
}
```

Comment: via[0].Response is nil (at least for go1.21.3) but it is a good idea to check if redirect is acceptable for your use case using req.URL or some other data. For example, you may want to restrict a redirect to a set of specific domains.